# Powershell - Verifying contents of zip files

Tags: hash, zip, compression, .net-4.5, powershell-3.0

I wrote a simple powershell script that takes a set of files and compresses them into a zip file using the ZipFile .NET Framework class. What I'd like to do is to verify that the file compressed without issues.

I can create a hash value for the zip file itself, but I'm unsure as to how to do this with each individual file in the the archive or compare each uncompressed file to the compressed version of the file. Here's the compression piece of my script.

```
$FileList | ForEach-Object -Begin {
$Zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open("Destination.Zip","Create")
} -Process {
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($Zip,$_.FullName,$_.Name,"optimal")
} -End {
$Zip.Dispose()
}
```

I know the compression piece works, however the eventual goal is to verify each file and redo that file if the verification fails. Afterwards delete the uncompressed files.

The system this is to run on only has powershell v3 and no third party compression tools are installed. I'd like to stick with that if possible.

Comment: Zip folder A, unzip in folder B, compare A and B, delete A and B if OK.

Comment: Though I did think of this as a possible solution, these are large log files with a compression ration of about 99%. To uncompress them would cause additional load on the server that I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I can imagine. Looking for a way to test without this ... harrass Google : )

Comment: I did. I have not found anything were someone mentions verifying compressed files anywhere. I've tried some technet articles as well and the scripting guy site from microsoft. No answers there either.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your most direct shot would be to use 7-Zip.

You can use native commands in PowerShell.

You can find an example use of the `-t` switch [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).

Get the CLI, [add 7-Zip folder to your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096037/how-to-properly-set-path-in-powershell-and-7zip) and run for example:

```
7z t archive.zip
```

Comment: So no way to do this without third party systems? I could have written the code to create the archive with 7zip commands, but was able to find a way to do so without installing anything. That's the real goal here.